# What does Jesus wear on his hand?

Tags: props, the-big-lebowski

In "The Big Lebowski", what does Jesus wear on his hand?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a Storm Gizmo wrist support bowling glove:
https://thetake.com/product/99449/john-turturro-storm-gizmo-wrist-support-glove-the-big-lebowsk

[image: Storm Gizmo]